# Configure MassTransit in one place (shared project)

Tags: c#, .net, masstransit

I have a modular monolith app and I want to register mass transit configuration on a single place inside shared project.

I have 4 projects

- project A
- project B
- project API
- shared

Consumers are located in the project A and project B.
Events are located in the shared project.
Project API starts the application and it will call mass transit configuration

```
public class ProjectAConsumer : IConsumer<MyEvent>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MyEvent> context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
} 

public class ProjectBConsumer : IConsumer<YourEvent>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<YourEvent> context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
} 

public class MyEvent : IEvent
{
}

public class YourEvent : IEvent
{
}
```

This is my mass transit configuration.

> var eventTypes = allTypes.Where(x => x.BaseType ==
> typeof(IEvent)).ToList(); //===> always returns 0 in count

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMassTransitV2(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMassTransit(configure =>
        {
            configure.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

            var allTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()).ToList();
            
            var eventTypes = allTypes.Where(x => x.BaseType == typeof(IEvent)).ToList(); //===> always 0 in count

            var consumerTypes = allTypes.Where(x =>
                eventTypes.Any(et => x.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IConsumer<>).MakeGenericType(et)))).ToList();

            configure.AddConsumers(consumerTypes.ToArray());

            configure.UsingRabbitMq((context, configurator) =>
            {
                var rabbitSettings = context.GetService<IOptions<RabbitMqSettings>>().Value;
                var host = new Uri("rabbitmq://" + rabbitSettings.ConnectionUrl);

                configurator.Host(rabbitSettings.ConnectionUrl, h =>
                {
                    h.Username(rabbitSettings.Username);
                    h.Password(rabbitSettings.Password);
                });

                if (consumerTypes.Any())
                {
                    // rabbitSettings.QueueName => service-b
                    configurator.ReceiveEndpoint(rabbitSettings.SusiModuleTestQueue, e =>
                    {
                        //e.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(InboxFilter<>), context);
                        e.ConfigureConsumers(context);
                    });
                }
            });
        });

        return services;
    }
```

If it matters I'm using

```
<PackageReference Include="MassTransit.RabbitMQ" Version="8.0.16" />
```

and .net 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interfaces are not base types, so checking `BaseType` is never going to find an interface.

`type.HasInterface<IEvent>()` (a MassTransit extension method) would work.